# Why wont glDrawElements render my triangles?

Tags: c++, opengl

i have been following the 3D game engine tutorial series by theBennyBox on youtube. the series is done in java and i like c++ because of computing speed reasons, i followed the tutorials all the way up to #15 where he starts using glDrawElements instead of glDrawArrays. up until now in the tutorials i have been fine converting his java code to c++ but now i can draw anything and opengl is giving me no errors. im almost sure that the problem is buffering the data for opengl or telling opengl how the data is buffered. here is my code.

mainGame.cpp:

init:

```
glClearColor(0.1f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
glFrontFace(GL_CW);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB);

vector<Vertex> vertices;
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1, 1, 0));
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0, -0.5f, 0));
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1, -1, 0));
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0));
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1, -1, 0));
vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(0, 0.5, 0));

vector<unsigned short> indices;
indices.push_back(0);
indices.push_back(1);
indices.push_back(2);
indices.push_back(3);
indices.push_back(4);
indices.push_back(5);

mesh.meshInit();
mesh.addVerticies(vertices, indices);
mesh.draw();
```

gameLoop:

```
    while (_gameState != GameState::EXIT) {
        processInput();
        updateScene();
        drawScene();
        if (_TEST)
        {
            GLenum err;
            while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
                cout << "OpenGL error: " << err << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

processInput() currently affects nothing having to do with opengl drawing, and updateScene() only clears the screen, and updates a transformation object but this is not the problem. i know because i  tried commenting that section out and nothing is still rendered / drawn by opengl.

drawScene:

```
shader.bind();
shader.setUniform("translation", transform.getTransformation());
mesh.draw();
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);
```

Here are the mesh class's functions that i believe i am not sending the correct information.

mesh.cpp:

```
void Mesh::meshInit()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
}

void Mesh::addVerticies(vector<Vertex> vertices, vector<unsigned short> indices)
{
    _indices = &indices[0];

    _vSize = vertices.size() * sizeof(float);
    _iSize = indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short);

    if (_TEST) {
        cout << "size of verticies: " << _vSize << endl;
        cout << "size of indices: " << _iSize << endl;
        cout << "number of verticies: " << vertices.size() << endl;
        cout << "number of indices: " << indices.size() << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size() ; i++)
        {
            cout << vertices[i].getPos().x << " ";
            cout << vertices[i].getPos().y << " ";
            cout << vertices[i].getPos().z << " ";
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }    

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vSize, &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _iSize, &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}

int vertexAtribStride = Vertex::SIZE * sizeof(float);

void Mesh::draw()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexAtribStride, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, _iSize, GL_INT, _indices);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Comment: Reduce. Remove everything but trying to draw one triangle with fixed coordinates. Perfect that, then move on to adding complexity. If you run into problems with that, you will have a [minimal compilable and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that will be much easier to work with than a spray of little snippets of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument of glDrawElements should be GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT and the last argument should be 0 since it is the offset from the start of the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER. Other than that I don't know what Vertex::SIZE is, but since you only have one attribute you can set the stride for glVertexAttribPointer to 0 so that OpenGL will just assume it they are tightly packet (which they are)

Comment: "The third argument of glDrawElements should be GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT" Based on what? It should match the type of the `_indices` value being passed, but that's not given.

Comment: Well yes they are. He is using GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER which was uploaded with vector<unsigned short> indices?

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that he was using an index buffer. Though in that case, the last parameter should be an offset from the start of the buffer; passing in a host memory pointer is meaningless and wrong.

Comment: yes! I wasn't sure if that was just a variable set to 0 or not, but he is clearly setting it to _indices = &indices[0]; I'll include that in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @bofjas what does the last argument mean, from this page: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawElements.xhtml and others like it i believed that it wanted a reference to the data/(the first element in the array) EDIT: i now see you specified this in your initial answer